# Limits vs Confidence Interval, the difference?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, confidence-interval

Below is a question on "limits" and confidence interval. The answers are below.

Why does question b) not require dividing by the square root of 10, but the confidence interval in question c) does?

Question:

[image]

Answer:

[image]

Comment: prediction interval vs confidence interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In part (c) you're asked about the **mean weight of a sample** of the tubs and requires the Central Limit Theorem. That means you use $s_{\bar x} = s/\sqrt{n}$ for your standard deviation.

Comment: So even if question b) said "find confidence limits" because it doesn't mention "mean" you don't divide by root(n)?